# Easily invalidate form in comment_post hook

Tags: comments

```php
$GLOBALS['test'] = 'a';

function comment_post_check($comment_ID, $comment_approved, $commentdata) 
{    
    $GLOBALS['test'] = 'b';        
}

add_action('comment_post', 'comment_post_check', 10, 3);
```

But my in my single.php, `echo $GLOBALS['test'];` always returns **a** even after comment post.

I guess that this because of a POST redirect and probably need to store in sessions only ?
Is there no easier way to set a `new WP_Error` and get that shown as an error by the default WordPress like it does in **Duplicate comment detected; it looks as though you’ve already said that!** ?

I thought I could set some pre-defined WP error variables and it'll viola show the error UI magically.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I could come up with is :

```php
function comment_post_check() 
{
    if ($_POST['email'] == 'someone@somewhere.com')
        wp_die( __('Error: Someone from Somewhere, you are banned') );

}

add_action('pre_comment_on_post', 'comment_post_check', 10);
```